# iOS UITableView Default swipe delete button not showing when i swipe the cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

UITableview default swipe delete button was not showing .........

i put the following methods for default swipe delete ....

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
   return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
(............)
}
```

My Mac was newly purchased one...

The swipe delete button is showing and also working in my friends Mac which was purchased before one year  ... 
But In My Mac Swipe is working  but the delete button is not showing......

Comment: Check the UITableViewDataSource connection properly. I think you did not connect the UITableViewDataSource.

Comment: Which version of the Xcode you are using. ?

Answer (score 1):

you should apply Auto layout constraints for **UITableView** through Storyboard.

Comment: Turned out to be my problem! Just came here to support this line of debugging for those who have reviewed properties and delegate code and still getting issues!